# Some radio buttons won't stay checked when modified in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This problem has recently come (specifically in Chrome), where our some of the radio buttons aren't clicking or have to be clicked many times in order to remain checked.

Here is the snippet (skip to the last chunk of code):

```
var createNetworkList = function(parent, ssid){
  var randToken = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
  var radio = document.createElement('input');
  radio.type = 'radio';
  radio.value = ssid;
  radio.id = ssid + randToken;
  radio.name = 'ssid';
  radio.className = 'radio radio-input' ;
  var parentDiv = document.createElement('DIV');

  var div = document.createElement('DIV');
  parentDiv.className = 'field';
  div.className = 'ui radio checkbox radio-div';
  div.appendChild(radio);
  var label = document.createElement('label');
  label.htmlFor = ssid;
  label.innerHTML = ssid;
  div.appendChild(label);
  parentDiv.appendChild(div)
  parent.appendChild(parentDiv);

  // HERE IS WHERE THE TROUBLE IS HAPPENING
  parentDiv.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.checked = true
    debugger // when you type `this.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.checked` it says `true`
    return true
  })

};
```

First, I made sure that they all unique ID's, that didn't work. Next, I made sure that it my onclick was returning sometihng at the end, that didn't work either. I tried a variety of things, **but this code was working for a long time, until recently. How complex should the fix be?**

Here is the HTML that is generated:

```
<div class="grouped fields" id="networks-div" style="display: block;">
  <div class="field" style="border-left: 1px solid gainsboro;">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox radio-div">
      <input type="radio" value="React-Wireless" id="React-Wirelessri99pzth88f" name="ssid" class="radio radio-input">
      <label for="React-Wireless">React-Wireless</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field" style="border-left: 1px solid gainsboro;">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox radio-div">
      <input type="radio" value="Charzinder-9PGP" id="Charzinder-9PGPr5cm2bz0k1b" name="ssid" class="radio radio-input">
      <label for="Charzinder-9PGP">Charzinder-9PGP</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field" style="border-left: 1px solid gainsboro;">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox radio-div">
      <input type="radio" value="Jhatka" id="Jhatkabg0vq1mfv5d" name="ssid" class="radio radio-input">
      <label for="Jhatka">Jhatka</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field" style="border-left: 1px solid gainsboro;">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox radio-div">
      <input type="radio" value="ORDGuest" id="ORDGuestzg0qcdhv6k" name="ssid" class="radio radio-input">
      <label for="ORDGuest">ORDGuest</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field" style="border-left: 1px solid gainsboro;">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox radio-div">
      <input type="radio" value="CharzinderWifi-Office-2.4G" id="CharzinderWifi-Office-2.4Gkfd9zl8hq" name="ssid" class="radio radio-input">
      <label for="CharzinderWifi-Office-2.4G">CharzinderWifi-Office-2.4G</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could we get the relevant HTML as well please.

Comment: The HTML is generated on the fly, but I can add what it spits out

Comment: Your `label` `for` attribute does not match the nearby `input` `id` attribute.

Comment: "`but this code was working for a long time, until recently. How complex should the fix be?`" ... I suppose that depends entirely on what changes you made to it.

Comment: @SamAxe, still didn't work. I added the `randToken` to the ID today. It doesn't work with or without it. ie. doesn't work even when labels and the input ID's are the same.